# Get line number of segfault using signal handler

Tags: c

I'm running a program on a remote machine that I can only interact with using stdout. I have a segfault somewhere in the program and I'm trying to figure out where. Is it possible to write a signal handler for sigsegv that gives me the line number and the file where it happened?

Comment: Why can't you use gdb on a remote machine to backtrace the segfault?

Comment: I don't have full access to this system. I can only submit my C files there and it will execute the binary and give me the output.

Comment: That will get you the *address* of the fault. Provided they're compiling your code to include debug info, you're going to have to do *a lot* of work to parse the DWARF data to determine the actual line number. It would be far easier to build this locally and debug it with traditional methods (i.e. gdb).

Comment: You could try `system("addr2line --help");` in a simple program to check if it is available on this system, if yes, then write a signal handler which calls it for the instruction pointer where the signal occurred.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a horrible debugging environment, but if it's really infeasible to get GDB running, you could try the following (assuming Linux):

1. Register a handler for `SIGSEGV`, `SIGBUS`, or whatever you think the fatal signal is using `sigaction()`, and pass `sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO`. Use the `sa_sigaction` rather than `sa_handler` member of `struct sigaction` to register the handler.
2. The handler will receive a `void *context` argument. Assuming X86_64 (you will have to figure out what the corresponding index is for the instruction pointer on other architectures), you can get the address where the signal was triggered via `((ucontext_t*)context)->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]`.
3. Once you have the address, run e.g. `addr2line -Cfip -e <binary with debugging symbols> <address>` to get the function and line number. (If you're cross-compiling, you need to use the `addr2line` from the toolchain, which will probably have some prefix, e.g. `arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line`.)

(Incidentally, I just recalled the `context` signal handler argument from another question. :)

A limitation to the above approach is that it probably won't give you a line number for crashes inside libraries -- especially if they're loaded at random addresses.

Another approach is to use `backtrace(3)`, which is available in glibc and a few other libc's. Bit hackish, but you could write the addresses you get from it (as strings) to `popen("addr2line -Cfip -e <binary with debugging symbols>")` (`/proc/self/exe` could be used too on Linux) to generate a backtrace with line numbers on `stdout`. `backtrace_symbols_fd()` is worth looking into too, though it won't give you line numbers. It needs `-rdynamic` when compiling.

**Edit:**

It seems GDB uses `personality(2)` and `ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE` to turn of address space randomization for libraries (would prolly need to be followed by a re-`execve()`). If you're really desperate, maybe that (or `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`) could be used to get line numbers inside libraries too.